# Improvement of classification of compact surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Can we improve the classification of compact surfaces by requiring that every smooth 2 dimensional compact manifold is diffeomorphic and not just homeomorphic to some torus or projective plane?

Answer (score 7):

In dimensions 1, 2, and 3, two homeomorphic smooth manifolds are [diffeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Homeomorphism_and_diffeomorphism).  So requiring diffeomorphism is no stronger than homeomorphism.

One might latch onto "smooth" in the previous, but the categories of smooth, piecewise-linear, and topological manifolds are identical in each of dimensions 1, 2, and 3.  This means each homeomorphism class of topological manifolds in those dimensions has a smooth member, which is also piecewise-linear.  So even a non-smooth topological manifold of dimension 2 is homeomorphic to a smooth manifold.

For dimension 2, that each homeomorphism class has a (canonical) piecewise-linear member is Rado's theorem: topological manifolds of dimension 2 are always triangulable by an essentially unique triangulation (up to piecewise-linear equivalence).  ([more on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)#Piecewise_linear_structures) and see also [Hauptvermutung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung) of geometric topology -- the falsehood that this continues to higher dimensions)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @GiulioBinosi : Glad to help.  The gradual divergence between the categories of smooth, piecewise-linear, and topological manifolds as dimension increases was fascinating to me when I first learned about it.